# Replacement for hook_user_presave() for saving values captured in the user form to the user profile

Tags: forms, users, hooks, 9

I am porting a module from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. The code uses `hook_user_presave()` to save two fields on the fly into the user profile data.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_presave().
 */
function affiliate_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $edit['data']['affiliate_optin'] = isset($edit['affiliate_optin']) ? $edit['affiliate_optin'] : 0;
  $edit['data']['affiliate_homepage'] = isset($edit['affiliate_homepage']) ? $edit['affiliate_homepage'] : FALSE;
}
```

The similar one in Drupal 9 seems to be `hook_entity_presave()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave() for user entities.
 */
function uber_affiliate_user_presave(UserInterface $account) {
  // code here
}
```

However there is only a single parameter to the function and so the edit values in the user profile form submit are not available here. So this means that there are better alternatives in Drupal 9.

I am thinking of writing an event subscriber, but it won't get the form submitted values.

Comment: Does this old change record answer the question? https://www.drupal.org/node/1554986

Comment: Well this looks a good start. However how do I get the values in form submit into presave. This seems to have been predesigned that way in Drupal 7 with the $edit parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out from @cilefen, the `$edit` parameter has been removed from the parameter passed to `hook_user_presave()`, which (starting from Drupal 8) is now documented under [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/9.3.x). [$edit argument removed from hook_user_update/insert/presave()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1554986) is the relevant change record.

The only way to get the submitted form values is to add a form submission handler to the form with `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. Form submission handlers, like form validation handlers(), have access to the submitted values via `$form_state->getValue()`, to get a single submitted value, or `$form_state->getValues()`, to get an array containing all the submitted values.

Also, what that code saves in `$edit['data']` now needs to be saved with [`UserData::set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserData.php/function/UserData%3A%3Aset/9.3.x). Since that class is used to implement a service, the correct code to use it is similar to the following one.

```
$user_data = Drupal::service('user.data');
$user_data->set($module, $uid, $name, $value);
```

The parameters are the following.

- `$module`
  the machine name of the module that is saving the data
- `$uid`
  the user ID to which the data is associated
- `$name`
  the name associated with the saved data
- `$data`
  the data to save

To get the already saved data, or to check it has been already saved, there is [`UserData::get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserData.php/function/UserData%3A%3Aget/9.3.x). Passing `$module`, `$uid`, and `$name` that method will return `NULL` when the data hasn't been yet saved.

The change record that documents the new *user.data* service is [users.data column replaced with user_data API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1852360).

Comment: I think hook_ENTITY_presave is called before form submit is handler is called as I am not able to get the values inside hook_user_presave.

Comment: `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` is invoked from the form submission handler for the form to edit an entity or create an entity. The answer isn't suggesting to use that hook, but to add a form submission handler to the edit form.

Comment: *The only way to get the submitted form values is to add a form submission handler to the form with `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.* How to add a form submission handler has not changed, passing from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks got it now.